# For comprehension parsing of optional string to int

Tags: string, scala, for-comprehension, scala-option

Say I have the following for comprehension:

```
val validatedInput = for {
    stringID <- parseToInt(optionalInputID)
} yield (stringID)
```

where optionalInputID is an input parameter of type `Option[String]`. I want to be able to convert an Option[String] into just a String, if of course there is an option present. As far as I'm aware, you cannot case match inside a for comprehension.

Some details have been omitted, such as other for comprehension items. Therefore I would like to know if it's possible to do this inside the for comprehension. If not, then what's a suitable alternative? Can I do it outside of the for comprehension?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add it to the `for comprehension`:

```
val validatedInput = for {
  inputID <- optionalInputID
  stringID <- parseToInt(inputID)
} yield (stringID)
```

It will work only if `parseToInt` has type of `Option`. If it returns something of `Try`, you can't do it - because you can't mix `Try` and `Option` in the same for-comprehension.

If `parseToInt` returns `Try`, you can do the following:

```
val validatedInput = for {
  inputID <- optionalInputID
  stringID <- parseToInt(inputID).toOption
} yield (stringID)
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch error. Could that be because of the possibility that there is a Some or None case?

Comment: I updated my answer, what is the return type of `parseToInt`?

Comment: `Expression of type Option[(ID, int, String)] doesn't conform to the expected type Either[A1_, B1_]` The `ID` and `int` being the other statements in the for comprehension (that I want to omit the details of for this question).

Comment: I understand if this is entirely unhelpful. I'll try and update my question to accommodate this error that I just commented.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to convert an Option[String] into just a String.
>
> Therefore I would like to know if it's possible to do this inside the for comprehension

In Scala, `for-comprehension` desugars into a combinitation of `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, none of which allows to extract the value out of the `Option`.

> If not, then what's a suitable alternative? Can I do it outside of the for comprehension?

To do so you can use one of `get` (unsafe), or it safer version `getOrElse`, or `fold`:

```scala
val validatedInput: Option[String] = Some("myString")

scala>validatedInput.get
// res1: String = "myString"

scala>validatedInput.getOrElse("empty")
// res2: String = "myString"

scala>validatedInput.fold("empty")(identity)
// res3: String = "myString"
```

Comment: Adding getOrElse to my statement seems to have worked. `stringID <- idFromString(inputID.getOrElse(""))`. Also, I have changed my statement. I do not need an int. I need an ID. But that seems to work. Thanks!